# how can I run a graphical program from ssh?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, video, ffmpeg

Before you get all, vote to close, thread like this other one, hear me out.
I have a program, it produces an image stream. I want to feed that stream to an ffmpeg session on the same machine.  The problem is I am connected to the machine, by ssh. I personally,  would prefer not to see visual output of the program. I just want to pipe the output to ffmpeg, so I can set up a stream on my server, and view it from there.

when I try to run the program, I get an error that amounts to not being able to forward the display.

```
./capture | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -s 640x480 -r 30 -i - -an -f avi -r 30 foo.mp4
...
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(Name:22073): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 221184 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 640x480, 221184 kb/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
```

But I don't want to send the graphical output of the program to my remote session, I just want it to run on the remote machine. I have tried sending the command to the background with `bg`, but the output then is:

```
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

So how can I make the program execute its graphical window on the remote machine, without having it try to send me the video stream via ssh?

If I were to drive to where the server is, and run the command,

```
 ./capture | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -s 640x480 -r 30 -i - -an -f avi -r 30 foo.mp4
```

Im sure it would run, and be fine, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Not a solution to your particular issue, but your command could use some improvements. Use the proper [rawvideo demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo) options: use `-pixel_format`, `-video_size`, `-framerate` instead of `-pix_fmt`, `-s`, `-r`. The input probably has no audio, so you can omit `-an` (not that leaving it does anything bad). `-f avi` is telling `ffmpeg` to use the AVI muxer, but your output is using the `.mp4` extension. Either omit `-f` or if it is required for scripting use `-f mp4`. The output `-r 30` is superfluous.

Comment: Is there an X session already running on the remote machine, and does the same user own it? Have you set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to that of the remote session?

Comment: Does thing produce an image stream on stdout? "If I were to drive to where the server is, and run the command, ... Im sure it would run" .. I'm not so sure.

Comment: The remote server cannot execute any graphical window at all, for any reason. That's why it throws the Mir error. ffmpeg can, according to Google, be run headless with a bit of tweaking.